# How to Upgrade Parse from version 1.7.1 to 1.12.0

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I found this online which is almost 2 years old https://parse.com/questions/what-is-the-best-way-to-update-the-parse-sdk-in-my-ios-app which suggests to delete the Parse.Framework from the current project and replace with the updated Parse.Framework, however, I was getting a lot of errors (see below).

Also, the current project I need to update has the ParseUI.framework, ParseFacebookUtils.Framework, and ParseCrashReporting.framework.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you update Parse.framework, you also need to update to the corresponding Bolts.framework (downloaded with Parse). That should solve the build errors.

Comment: I have updated Bolts.framework and it resolved the BFTask errors but I have am getting the Parse/PFNullability.h file not found error?

Comment: The remaining error appears to be due to the ParseFacebookUtils.framework needing to be updated as it still references Parse/PFNullability.h which no longer exists. Any ideas on this?